# How to enable qTranslate languages tabs in custom plugin page

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-qtranslate

For example, I have created a custom post creator. I am using `wp_editor()` to generate "WYSIWYG" editors for content.

I am using `qTranslate` for multi-language user experience. Unfortunately I am forced to create a separate "WYSIWYG" editor for every language translation. Overkill.

How to enable / implement `qTranslate` language tabs as they are in default post creator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - I would think that the qtranslate plugin will add the tabs to the wp_editor() editor automatically.
At least , it was doing it when I used it for CPT ..

2 - there is [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-extended/) which helps plugin authors to implement qtranslate in own plugins .

3 - there is a filter `add_filter(‘the_editor’, ‘qtrans_modifyRichEditor’);` in qtranslate you might want to investigate

4 - you can also use a simple loop in order to create the tabs using `qtrans_getLanguage()`

Comment: Hi krembo99, can you explain this steps a little detailed?

Comment: Which step are you referring to ?

Comment: Ițm referring on step 3